# Error: "Failed to map the path '/'" when I add a Telerik ReportViewer to web page

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-reporting

I've just built a crap load of Telerik reports for my web site project, and they all work nicely.  I have to demonstrate them tomorrow, and tried to build a viewing page that hosts their web ReportViewer.  I have asked this question on their forums as well, but expect less response than from SO late on a Friday night.

Whether I use GAC or bin references, as soon as I add the ReportViewer control to my page, even without trying to load a report, I get the error `Failed to map the path '/'`.  Other Telerik controls, from the Web.UI library work fine.  I'm not expecting a Telerik specific answer here, although that would ease the pain of my all-nighter, but I can see nothing meaningful in the stack trace for this error.

How can I go about diagnosing what Telerik is looking for and can't find, or something of that ilk?  This is a serious emergency, and I will sort a 'dereferenced' bounty for anyone that can offer any suggestions tonight.  I'm going to reinstall Reporting so long.

UPDATE:  Foolishly wary of excess complicating factors, I always try new things like this in a small, dedicated project separate from my main one.  Yesterday I quickly tried a small web *site* project when I encountered my problem.  I then tried a small web *application* project, with local, not GAC references to telerik, all telerik refs set to copy to local, and it all worked.  Naturally I was quite ecstatic, as my main project is a web *app*, not *site*.

Comment: Can you give the full error message?  Is it System.Configuration?  This kind of sounds like a config file issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you have a webpage running without problems.
Than you add a telerik ReportViewer controls - run the things again and get an error:
...Failed...'/'...
The control simply sits in the page and does nothing.
So like womp I would ask you to provide the full error output!

One other question:
Does the error also occure on the development machine (running the project from VS with webdev server)?

And a hint meanwhile (not sure if you'v already checked this):
http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/reporting/general/deploying-telerik-reporting.aspx

One last thing - maybe it con help you. I made up a little web site doing what you have told your site does.
You can download it here: www.pp-p.com/rvsite.zip

Maybe a look at web.config or so can help you to find what's missing in your site.
One thing - in the BIN folder are two txt files - replace them with the DLLs from telerik reporting to have the project work.

Maybe this helps (for the weekend till the telerik support guys are back at work)..